# PigLatin translator for words starting with multiple consonants[Python]

Tags: python

```
VOWELS = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')


def pigLatin(word):
    first_letter = word[0]
    if first_letter in VOWELS:  # if word starts with a vowel...
        return word + "hay"     # then keep it as it is and add hay to the end
    else:
        return word[1:] + word[0] + "ay"


def findFirstVowel(word):
    novowel = False
    if novowel == False:
        for c in word:
            if c in VOWELS:
                return c
```

I need to write a piglatin translator that can handle words that start with multiple consonants.

For example, the output I get currently when I enter "string" is:

`PigLatin("string") = tringsay`

I would want the output:

`PigLatin("string") = ingstray`

To write this, I wrote an additional function to iterate through the word and find the first vowel, but after that I am not sure how to proceed.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can show us your code to find the first vowel, and we can help you continue. =)

Comment: @justhalf He did. It's the second function in the question

Comment: Oh, Because it's not properly indented, I thought he left the function empty. Sorry

Comment: *Aside*: You assign VOWELS more easily: `VOWELS = 'aeiou'`

Comment: I have rolled back your edit summarised as "removed more identifying information" because first, I don't understand how the string `"string"` used as an example of a string counts as "identifying", second because the string you replaced it with (`"matters"`) doesn't show the problem described in the question, and third because the sample output given for that string made no sense in the context.

Answer (score 1):

After finding the first vowel, get its index in the string by doing `word.index(c)`. Then, slice the whole word from the beginning to the index of the vowel

With that slice, put it at the end of the word and add `'ay'`, as you did in your first function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the index of a consonant and slice on it.

Here's an example:

```
def isvowel(letter): return letter.lower() in "aeiou"

def pigLatin(word):
    if isvowel(word[0]):     # if word starts with a vowel...
        return word + "hay"  # then keep it as it is and add hay to the end
    else:
        first_vowel_position = get_first_vowel_position(word)
        return word[first_vowel_position:] + word[:first_vowel_position] + "ay"

def get_first_vowel_position(word):
    for position, letter in enumerate(word):
        if isvowel(letter):
            return position
    return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably more eloquent ways of doing this but this is my solution. Hopefully it helps!

```
def pigLatin(aString):
    index = 0
    stringLength = len(aString)
    consonants = ''

    # if aString starts with a vowel then just add 'way' to the end
    if isVowel(aString[index]): 
        return aString + 'way' 
    else:
    # the first letter is added to the list of consonants
        consonants += aString[index]
        index += 1

        # if the next character of aString is a vowel, then from the index 
        # of the vowel onwards + any consonants + 'ay' is returned
        while index < stringLength:
            if isVowel(aString[index]):
                return aString[index:stringLength] + consonants + 'ay'
            else:
                consonants += aString[index]
                index += 1
        return 'This word does contain any vowels.'

def isVowel(character):
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    return character in vowels
```